# Is the partion's high watermark actually one greater than the offset of the last message in the partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have an empty topic with one partition (and one replica), and I query for the low/high watermarks, it comes back at 0/0.  If I have one message in the partition, it comes back at 0/1.  But to get the last (and only message), I have to start reading from 0.  In particular, my app has a need, on startup, to read the latest (last written) message in the partition.  So I'm using this code:

```
 consumer.Assign(new[] { new TopicPartitionOffset(topicPartition, new Offset(last - 1)) });
```

when the last offset > 0. (last is the return value for the high watermark)

This seems to work but it doesn't seem to conform to the docs that I've read that indicate that the high watermark is the offset of the last replicated message.  From my experimentation, it appears to be one higher.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: If the topic has one message, the offset for that message is at offset 0... But there is one message, so the watermark is at 1... Not sure I understand the question, though

Comment: I think you are confirming my understanding in that the high watermark is one greater than the offset of the last message. I didn’t get that understanding from the docs. I thought it implied that the high watermark == the offset of the last message which doesn’t seem to be the case.

Comment: It is the offset where the next message would be written

Comment: I can confirm what @OneCricketeer said.